# How to use for loop to calculate midpoint rule Riemann Sum in C

Tags: c

For an assignment, I am supposed to create a function that calculates PI by using the midpoint rule Riemann  sums of a quarter of a circle. I am having trouble getting the correct output as I think something about my logic is wrong. Here is my code for the function:

```
#include <math.h>

double circle_pi(int rectangles)
{
  int radius = 2;
  int i;
  int width = (double)radius / (double)rectangles;
  double rect_area = 0;

  for(i = 1; i<= rectangles; i++)
  {

    int midpoint = (double)width / 2;

    int height = sqrt((radius * radius) - (midpoint * midpoint));

    midpoint = midpoint + width;

    rect_area = (double)width * (double)height;

   }

  return rect_area;
}
```

Here is the main function:

```
#include <stdio.h> /* scanf, printf */

double circle_pi(int rectangles);  /* Calculates PI using a quarter circle */
double leibniz_pi(int iterations); /* Calculates PI using a series         */

int main(void)
{
  int i; /* loop counter */

    /* Print out table header */
  printf("Approximations for pi\n");
  printf("Iterations      Circle Method   Leibniz Method\n");
  printf("----------------------------------------------\n");

    /* Print out values for each set of numbers */
  for (i = 1; i <= 1000000; i *= 10)
  {
      /* Calculate PI with both methods */
    double pi_circle = circle_pi(i);
    double pi_leibniz = leibniz_pi(i);

      /* Print the results of the calculations */
    printf("%10i%20.12f%16.12f\n", i, pi_circle, pi_leibniz);
  }

  return 0; /* Return success to the OS */
}
```

And here is the expected output:

```
Approximations for pi
Iterations      Circle Method   Leibniz Method
----------------------------------------------
     1      3.464101615138  4.000000000000
    10      3.152411433262  3.041839618929
   100      3.141936857900  3.131592903559
  1000      3.141603544913  3.140592653840
 10000      3.141592998025  3.141492653590
100000      3.141592664482  3.141582653590
1000000      3.141592653934  3.141591653590
```

and her is the output I got from my code:

```
Approximations for pi
Iterations      Circle Method   Leibniz Method
----------------------------------------------
     1      2.000000000000  
    10      0.000000000000 
   100      0.000000000000
  1000      0.000000000000
 10000      0.000000000000
100000      0.000000000000
1000000      0.000000000000
```

(I have not worked on the other function yet which is why it is blank)

I am really sorry if the problem is obvious, but I am new to C and am having a difficult time getting accustomed to it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi there. You gave the expected output which is helpful, but you did not explain exactly what your problem is.

Comment: @Iguananaut Hello. I am sorry I just edited it to show what my output was. My problem is that the output for Circle Method does not match. Thank you so much for responding.

Comment: I think your `circle_pi` function has many problems. You need to think carefully about what types you want all your variables to have; many of them you have declared as `int`s when you probably want to them to be `double`. That would also avoid the many awkward, otherwise unnecessary `(double)` casts, and also cramming the results of floating point divisions into `int`s is hurting you (mostly they will be truncated to zero I think). Also you redefine your midpoint to `width/2` every time at the start of the loop, so it actually never increases; obviously not what you want.

Comment: You also overwrite the value of `rect_area` in the loop. You probably wanted a `+=` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Iguananaut already mentioned: you should use the `double` data type for all variables in `circle_pi` with the exception of the iterator for the loop.
You actual error is that you forgot to sum it all up at the end

```
double circle_pi(int rectangles)
{
  double radius = 2.0;
  int i;
  double width = radius / (double)rectangles;
  double rect_area = 0.0;
  double midpoint, height;
  // set startvalue of mipoint
  midpoint = width / 2.0;

  for(i = 1; i <= rectangles; i++)
  {
    height = sqrt((radius * radius) - (midpoint * midpoint));
    midpoint = midpoint + width;
    rect_area = rect_area + width * height;
   }
  return rect_area;
}
```

Which results in the expected output:

```
Approximations for pi
Iterations      Circle Method   Leibniz Method
----------------------------------------------
         1      3.464101615138
        10      3.152411433262
       100      3.141936857900
      1000      3.141603544913
     10000      3.141592998025
    100000      3.141592664486
   1000000      3.141592653923
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I realize how that works now. However, I noticed that the output from this is actually a little different from the expected output. Could this be because of a rounding error? And if so is it caused by adding the midpoint to itself? If that is the case, is there a way to calculate the midpoint without adding the previous one to itself? Again, thank you so much for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment above, but for example I would have written your function more like this (note: I have not tested this):

```
#define RADIUS 2.0
#define RADIUS2 4.0

double circle_pi(int rectangles)
{
  int idx;
  double width = RADIUS / rectangles;
  double x = width / 2;
  double total_area = 0;

  for(idx = 0; idx < rectangles; idx++)
  {
    height = sqrt(RADIUS2 - (x * x));
    total_area += width * height;
    x += width;
  }
  return total_area;
}
```

There are a few other tricks you can do with this to simplify. For example you can realize that the "width" is always the same and factor it out, reducing the number of multiplications.

Comment: Thank you! You have helped me so much. I was wondering though, is there a way to calculate the midpoint without adding the previous value to itself? I think that is causing a rounding error which makes this output slightly different than the expected output. Again I appreciate all of your help that you have given me.